# Shopify tag product filter not working with checkbox select

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, shopify, liquid

i'm trying to create a set of product filters that will work individually or as multiple selects. For test purposes i've added two sets of checkbox that separate different types of filtering options; Category and Size.

When you check one of the checkbox option, the page reloads, but with all of the available filtering options, not just one. The same goes for if you check multiple options, all are shown in the url as follows: **/collections/trending-products/ecommerce+woocommerce+wordpress+magento-2+xs+s+m+l+xl**

Here is the test filter i've created so far. The first block contains my HTML and Liquid tags for pulling in the assigned product tags and displaying them as checkboxes with label (which works). The second block contains my JavaScript. The script seems to work fine **if** I display my filers as a select rather than checkbox... The main issue i'm facing is that the checkboxes don't seem to assign the selected tag to the url in the same way as a select, but I can't work out where the problem lies.

Any help/advice with this would be gratefully appreciated : )

Thanks

```js
Shopify.queryParams = {};
  if (location.search.length) {
    for (var aKeyValue, i = 0, aCouples = location.search.substr(1).split('&'); i < aCouples.length; i++) {
      aKeyValue = aCouples[i].split('=');
      if (aKeyValue.length > 1) {
        Shopify.queryParams[decodeURIComponent(aKeyValue[0])] = decodeURIComponent(aKeyValue[1]);
      }
    }
  }
  jQuery('.coll-picker').change(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).val()) {
      location.href = '/collections/' + jQuery(this).val();
    }
    else {
      location.href = '/collections/all';
    }
  });
  var collFilters = jQuery('.coll-filter');
  collFilters.change(function() {
    delete Shopify.queryParams.page;
    var newTags = [];
    collFilters.each(function() {
      if (jQuery(this).val()) {
        newTags.push(jQuery(this).val());
      }
    });
    {% if collection.handle %}
    var newURL = '/collections/{{ collection.handle }}';
    if (newTags.length) {
      newURL += '/' + newTags.join('+');
    }
    var search = jQuery.param(Shopify.queryParams);
    if (search.length) {
      newURL += '?' + search;
    }
    location.href = newURL;
    {% else %}
    if (newTags.length) {
      Shopify.queryParams.constraint = newTags.join('+');
    }
    else {
      delete Shopify.queryParams.constraint;
    }
    location.search = jQuery.param(Shopify.queryParams);
    {% endif %}
  });
```

```html
<form class="lmwd-filter" method="get">
  <ul class="clearfix filter-category">
    <li>
      <p>Category</p>
      {% assign tags = 'Ecommerce, Woocommerce, WordPress, Magento 2' | split: ',' %}
      {% for t in tags %}
      {% assign tag = t | strip %}
      {% if current_tags contains tag %}
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="coll-filter" name="{{ tag | handle }}" value="{{ tag | handle }}" checked />
        {{ tag }}
      </label>
      {% else %}
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="coll-filter" name="{{ tag | handle }}" value="{{ tag | handle }}" />
        {{ tag }}
      </label>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Size</p>
      {% assign tags = 'XS, S, M, L, XL' | split: ',' %}
      {% for t in tags %}
      {% assign tag = t | strip %}
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="coll-filter" name="{{ tag | handle }}" value="{{ tag | handle }}" />
        {{ tag }}
      </label>
      {% endfor %}
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```